# How to show that R^n is not totally bounded for n>1

Tags: general-topology

I can show that R is not totally bounded, but how do I show that R^n is not totally bounded for n>1? Is this suppose to be a induction proof?

Comment: Totally bouded spaces are bounded. Incidentally, $\mathbb R$ is also not totally bounded.

Comment: Do you have the proof for $\mathbb{R}$? How could you translate this to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\varepsilon=1$ and suppose we can cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finitely many open balls of radius $\varepsilon$. Since there are finitely many, their centres are all distance at most $M<\infty$ from the origin (taking the maximum of each of the distances). Any point of distance larger than $M+1$ from the origin will hence not lie inside any of these balls.